Suggest a method to minimize non-linear function
in my program I need to minimize two following separate functions in real-time (initial approximations $(x_0, y_0)_i, i\in\overline{1, n}$ are given, all other letters represent constants which are also given as input; $n$ is expected to be $\le 5$; I estimate time budget around 10 ms roughly, c++ is used):
$$f((x_1, y_1),\dots,(x_n, y_n)):\quad(A - \sum_{i=1}^n y_i \cos{x_i})^2 + (B - \sum_{i=0}^n y_i \sin{x_i})^2 \to min$$
$$\text{subject to: } a_i\le x_i\le b_i, i\in\overline{1, n}\quad c_i\le y_i\le d_i, i\in\overline{1, n}$$
and
$$f((x_1, y_1),\dots,(x_n, y_n)):\quad(C - \sum_{i=1}^n y_i (\alpha_i\sin{x_i} - \beta_i\cos{x_i}))^2 \to min$$
$$\text{subject to: } a_i\le x_i\le b_i, i\in\overline{1, n}\quad c_i\le y_i\le d_i, i\in\overline{1, n}$$
I don't need to find the exact solution (although it is desirable), "good enough" will do. Can someone please suggest which methods are better suited for these particular functions? I was thinking about gradient-like (but changing one coordinate at a time, since partial derivatives can be easily found) shifting or Lagrange multipliers, but I'm really not sure: last time I did optimization was long time ago in uni. Any remarks are appreciated.

Nelder-Mead algorithm is pretty easy to implement and it can handle box constraints like this pretty well. If you want to use more sophisticated techniques then you will probably have to find a dedicated library as they can be quite laborious to write yourself

so the problem is that at each time step you are given a different set of $A,B,C,\alpha_i,\beta_i$ and you want to solve for $x_i,y_i$?

@user619894, that is correct. $a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i$ constraints are also part of a input set.
